# Why doesn't my margin-left work properly?

Tags: css, web

Why is the indent on the lines in the continuation of the disclaimer span at the bottom not affected by the the

```
.footer-text {
margin-left: 5%;
}
```

I put in the css?

[image: Notice the indent]

The website is at http://jackgreenearth.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that footer text is in a `span`, which is not a block element. If you change it to a `div` or add the css rule `display: block;`, it will work as you expect. You can find more information about `display` property at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#examples